# Automatic weights affect opposite side of the pants

Tags: weight-painting

Ok so I'm having this problem where i have these pants and i want to link them via mesh deform but when i try to apply automatic weights and even bone envelope weights, the bones will affect the opposite leg. So for example, i apply automatic weights to the right leg, and the heat map will go on the left leg. Does anyone have a reason for this and possible fix?

Comment: Does your mesh have negative scale or something weird?  Could you [upload a blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), perhaps?

Comment: The thing is it's only with the pants, every other part of the mesh it works just fine and apparently my file size is just slightly bigger than what stack exchange allows

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. Apparently I did have negative scaling. I just scaled the pants on the x axis until it flipped itself and now I've got proper weighting with bones.